# Changing colors of word's first letter in a sentence using only css rule

Tags: html, css

Changing colors of word's first letter in a sentence using only css rule. For check my code please see:

```
.right_img ul li::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n3qszd17/1/)

And i want this:

[image: need]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use javascript then you should try following code...

```js
$('.capitalize').each(function(){
    var text = this.innerText;
    var words = text.split(" ");
    var spans = [];
    var _this = $(this);
    this.innerHTML = "";
    words.forEach(function(word, index){
        _this.append($('<span>', {text: word}));
    });
});
```

```css
.capitalize {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.capitalize span {
    display: inline-block;    
}

.capitalize span:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='capitalize'>
    SOMETHING BETTER 
    SOMETHING BETTER 
    SOMETHING BETTER 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`::first-letter` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) will target only the first letter of the first line of an element (in your example, the "N", "E" & "S"). There is no CSS selector that will do what you are trying to do, the only way to achieve it would be to wrap the first letter of each word in another tag and use CSS to target that tag.